# Regular expression in CMake install command

Tags: regex, cmake

I have a folder with mixed source (.cpp) and header (.h and .hpp) files. How do I write a regex expression in the CMake install command for installing only header files into a specific destination?

My search for an example on how to use a regex expression in the CMake install command did not succeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [install documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:install):

> The FILES_MATCHING option may be given before the first match option to disable
>   installation of files (but not directories) not matched by any expression.

#### Usage

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(foo)

install(
    DIRECTORY
    "./src"
    DESTINATION
    "include/foo"
    FILES_MATCHING
    PATTERN
    "*.hpp"
)
```

#### Example

```
> cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`pwd`/_install
> cmake --build _builds/ --target install
> find src/ -type f
src/a.hpp
src/a.cpp
src/B/b.hpp
src/B/b.cpp
```

Only `*.hpp` files installed:

```
> find _install/ -type f
_install/include/foo/src/a.hpp
_install/include/foo/src/B/b.hpp
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I also wanted to include header files with .h extension. I tried the pattern "*(.hpp|.h)" it never worked. Any idea with the right expression?

Comment: you can add several `PATTERN "..."` options, and also some `PATTERN "..." EXCLUDE`