# CMake install header files and maintain directory hierarchy

Tags: cmake

Using cmake 2.8

I would like to maintain the directory hierarchy while copying the header files from the source to the destination directory. For example, the header file that needs to be copied are
abc/1.h, def/2.h and they should also be copied in the same order in the destination directly ( set via CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX )

This is what I have tried, but it just copies the header files and not the header files inclusive parent directory name

```
set(HEADERS "abc/1.h;def/2.h")
install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION include)
```

The final output should be dest_directory/abc/1.h and dest_directory/def/2.h.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have many files in the directory for install, you may consider to *install the directory* with `install(DIRECTORY)` command flow. You may select which files in the directory should be installed with *PATTERN* or *REGEX* options:

```
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/" # source directory
        DESTINATION "include" # target directory
        FILES_MATCHING # install only matched files
        PATTERN "*.h" # select header files
)
```

See [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/install.html#id5) for more information about the `install(DIRECTORY)`. Also, it describes meaning '/' at the end of source directory.

Comment: found an exact duplicate here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796048/regex-in-cmake-install-command

Comment: @infoclogged: On Stack Overflow *answers* cannot be duplicate, only *questions*. Referenced answer explains similar things like my one, but do that from a different point of view, as the questions are different.

Comment: I was actually referring to the question, but after your post, I realised its different. Thank you for the hint :)

Comment: I would recommend using CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR if you have a multi-level hierarchy directory.

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of the question, we wanted to install all the headers in a `HEADER` variable, which would not necessarily include all headers in a given directory (for e.g., there might be platform dependent headers).

We adressed this problem with the following macro, which actually installs all the files given to `FILES` while creating the parent directories, if any:

```
macro(install_with_directory)
    set(optionsArgs "")
    set(oneValueArgs "DESTINATION")
    set(multiValueArgs "FILES")
    cmake_parse_arguments(CAS "${optionsArgs}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN} )

    foreach(FILE ${CAS_FILES})
        get_filename_component(DIR ${FILE} DIRECTORY)
        INSTALL(FILES ${FILE} DESTINATION ${CAS_DESTINATION}/${DIR})
    endforeach()
endmacro(install_with_directory)
```

Comment: That's a great option ! An example of how using the macro :
```install_with_directory(
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}/
  FILES ${HEADERS})```
with HEADERS a list of headers files with their directories.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer myself after trying a couple of times. It needs to be done in multiple steps.

```
install(FILES "abc/1.h" DESTINATION "include/abc")
install(FILES "def/2.h" DESTINATION "include/def")
```

In complicated situations, a REGEX can be used. Please see [Regex in CMake install command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796048/regex-in-cmake-install-command)